# Uso do ponto e vírgula no lugar de dois-pontos em versões recentes dos livros do Eça

Tags: pontuação

Estava comparando a edição que tenho de A Cidade e as Serras com o original disponível no [Wikisource](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Cidade_e_as_Serras) e encontrei divergências em relação ao uso do ponto e vírgula e dos dois-pontos. No seguinte trecho, os dois-pontos é usado na versão original, mas na minha edição usa-se ponto e vírgula em vez de dois-pontos:

> N’essa sua mudez e indecisão de sombra surdira, ao fim do luto do papá, o gosto muito vivo de tornear madeiras ao torno: depois, mais tarde, com a melada flôr dos seus vinte annos, brotou n’elle outro sentimento, de desejo e de pasmo, pela filha do desembargador Velho, uma menina redondinha como uma rôla, educada n’um convento de Paris, e tão habilidosa que esmaltava, dourava, concertava relogios e fabricava chapéos de feltro.

A troca acontece ainda em outros trechos.

Ainda mais, em alguns trechos onde a versão original usa ponto e vírgula, a minha edição usa dois pontos. Como no seguinte trecho:

> Obtive uma noção; tenho sobre ti, que com os olhos desarmados vês só o luzir da vidraça, uma vantagem positiva.

Importante notar que encontrei a mesma situação com outro livro de outra editora, desta vez, A Relíquia, da editora Book Cover do Porto, Portugal - o outro livro, A Cidade e as Serras, é da editora Ediouro do Rio de Janeiro, Brasil.

Alguém saberia justificar essa troca dos dois-pontos pelo ponto e vírgula e vice-versa?

Comment: Acho melhor perguntar a casa editora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo duas possibilidades para essas trocas: acidental (erro) ou proposital (correção/adaptação) e creio que aqui se trata desta última.

##### Erro

Em se tratando de livros antigos, digitalizados por software ou digitados à mão, a explicação mais simples para esse tipo de diferença é erro — no software de OCR ou na digitação. Contudo, "A Cidade e as Serras" não é tão antigo assim, e versões escaneadas que encontrei (e.g., [aqui](https://archive.org/details/acidadeeasserra00queigoog/page/n20/mode/2up) e [aqui](https://books.google.de/books?redir_esc=y&id=CBytxwEACAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=madeiras+ao+torno)) têm claramente dois-pontos (no seu primeiro exemplo), tornando erros menos prováveis, especialmente de OCR.

##### Adaptação

Embora haja valor, especialmente histórico, em se preservar a forma original de uma obra, também é importante preservar, dentro do possível, a intenção original do autor, assim como a legibilidade para leitores modernos. Nos dois exemplos dados, eu diria que o texto de Eça diverge do uso atual (i.e., depois de "torno" usaríamos ponto e vírgula, e, depois de "noção", dois-pontos), como também observa Tereza Moura Guedes, em *Falar Melhor, Escrever Melhor* (via [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/uma-possibilidade-estilistica-do-codigo-literario/2511#)):

> O emprego deste sinal [dois pontos] é dos que mais têm variado com os tempos e as modas. Camilo Castelo Branco e Eça de Queirós, por exemplo, empregavam-no em vez do ponto e vírgula.

Nota-se também que, por exemplo, essa [digitalização](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/pesquisa/DetalheObraForm.do?select_action&co_obra=1790) ([PDF](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000081.pdf)) feita pela Biblioteca Virtual do Estudante Brasileiro da USP, não apenas contém as trocas mencionadas na pergunta, como também troca "indifferente" por "indiferente" e também atualiza "commando", "janella", "grillo", "intelligente", "philosophia", etc., demonstrando o esforço de modernização da linguagem.

Esse tipo de atualização é comum, mas talvez seja mais notável em Eça de Queirós dado seu [prolífico uso](https://interruptor.pt/artigos/dos-pontos-e-das-virgulas) de sinais de pontuação.